# Newer ESRI software not able to read legacy ESRI grids created with ArcHydro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, esri-grid-format, migration

I'm trying to migrate older data generated using the ArcHydro (when it was standalone plugin that you could add to ArcMap). The data are standard hydrological raster products (flow direction, stream link, etc.) stored as ESRI grids.  All data layers were created from the same source (ASTER GDEM) and are in the same reference system (WGS84 UTM 17S).

I created these between July - August 2020, using the ArcHydro plugin in ArcMap 10.4.1, Windows 7 Pro.  This same computer has QGIS 3.13.3 (Bucuresti). Both ArcMap and QGIS and can display and manipulate these layers on the older setup.  These data cannot be displayed or manipulated when I migrate these same layers to a different workstation (Windows 11 Pro, ArcMap 10.8.1,  ArcGIS Pro 2.9.5, and QGIS 3.28.8, "Firenze").

The error that I get from AGP is (see the image),

"Add data
Failed to add data, unsupported data type. 'filename'
Failed to open raster dataset [Failed to open raster dataset]"

[image]

ArcMap on the newer workstation (ArcMap 10.8.1 on Windows 11 Pro) also returns the error
"Raster Data Objects Error
Invalid raster dataset.  Failed to create raster layer."

[image]

But, QGIS can display these data.  I can find a workaround by exporting the layers to another raster format in the older software or through QGIS.

It seems like this may be caused by a problem with the newer ESRI software or maybe operating system not being able to read the older ESRI grid format.  Does anyone have suggestions for how to fix this, so that the legacy datasets can be read directly into and used in the later ESRI software?

Comment: Can you share some test data?

Comment: I think you may be crossing streams here. ArcGIS tools read ArcInfo Grid format.  They don't read *corrupted* Grid format so well (passing around .adf files outside the Grid format multi-folder/multi-file structure may not retain validity).  At a minimum, we need a picture of the folder tree in a Windows Explorer window of the data files involved, and probably the folder above that.

Comment: Vince--thanks for suggestion.  I'm migrating the entire folder tree with these layers inside.  Your comment about 'passing files around' outside of folder hierarchies reminded me of something.  The older ArcHydro was finicky about file paths and naming conventions; best practices were to output files directly to the C: drive ("C:\ArcHydro").   If I migrate the legacy files to the same path, the newer AGP and ArcMap can read them. It still has difficulty with some tolls (e.g., export) but runs other successfully (e.g., reclass).

Comment: Path length and spaces in paths perhaps?

Comment: Grid had a strict "no spaces" policy. ~32 years later, I still have a "no spaces" policy.